# Extracting text from svg using python and selenium

Tags: selenium, python-behave

[image][image]enter image description here[image]

i came up with this xpath:-"//*[local-name()='text' and @style='text-anchor: middle; fill: rgb(0, 32, 96); font-family: Calibri; font-size: 40px; white-space: pre;']/*[local-name()='title']"

which gives me 3 element that i need t extract but couldn't get more unique then this.
Can someone help.

Thanks

Comment: You should share raw HTML comment rather than sharing image. And also highlight which 3 elements it’s is returning. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Can you try this : `//svg[@class='card']//title`

Comment: its hard to share the whole source i can share the 3 elemnts i get

Comment: for svg its name or local name that works

Comment: At least you can share HTML you have shared in image in text format. Also share HTML of other two elements identified.

Comment: shared all 3 images outter html dosent copy the whole thing as this is from power bi link giving out svg elements

Comment: I have tried this for day and half i want this to be solved i am very close just cant get unique to read the text or tspan where the data is

Comment: @Rahim : Have you tried with CSS Selector?

Answer (score 1):

If at all you are trying to find only these 3 elements/amount fields, I would suggest you can try the following CSS Selectors, should work.

```
svg[class='card'][aria-label*='PaymentReceived'] title


svg[class='card'][aria-label*='Change%'] title


svg[class='card'][aria-label*='ChangeFromPrevious'] title
```

Comment: Your Xpath - //[local-name()='text' and @style='text-anchor: middle; fill: rgb(0, 32, 96); font-family: Calibri; font-size: 40px; white-space: pre;']/[local-name()='title'] seems to be quite fragile and its very likely that there can be a placeholder element that's returning you the 3 elements but they would not be populated. In that case, choosing the label can be preferred as it might as well be the element that you need data from and would be populated.

Answer (score 0):

[Screen from console in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU66N.png)

Try to use:

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('svg>title')
element[9].textContent
```

in selenide with Java I use it like this:

```
element.getAttribute("textContent").contains("your text")
```