# Extract list of text from g element within svg tag using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

I would like to extract the following text fields that are located within a g tag which is located in a svg tag (the url: https://www.msci.com/our-solutions/esg-investing/esg-ratings-climate-search-tool). I put in a company name and search for it, expand the last drop down menu and want to extract information from the `<svg>`.

HTML Part I:

[image]

HTML Part II:

[image]

I tried what has been suggested here: [Extracting text from svg using python and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63771892/extracting-text-from-svg-using-python-and-selenium)
but I did not mange to get it.

My code:

```
test = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='highcharts-root']//*[local-name()='g' and @class='highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels']//*[name()='text']").text
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the texts e.g. *`Sep-18`*, *`Nov-22`* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg.highcharts-root g.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels text")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`get_attribute("innerHTML")`*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='highcharts-root']//*[local-name()='g' and @class='highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels']//*[local-name()='text']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Reading title tag in svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63544849/7429447)
- [Creating XPATH for svg tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49024531/7429447)

Comment: Thank you very much! the first option worked for me